# IE7 and IE6 are giving trouble with navigation using an unordered list (extra spacing etc.)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7

Hey guys!  I feel like I have gotten a good grasp on IE6 and 7 recently, but today I was working on a site and I just seem unable to fix this problem.

http://arboroaks.bythepixel.com/tyrone/

Check it out in Firefox and Chrome and IE8.  All looks good!  But then, go into IE7 and some extra padding gets added, as well as the links have to be clicked on the text for it to work.

Then open in IE6 for even more problems.

If anyone has some pointers that would be great; I'm pulling my hairs out here!

** Update **
I think it has to do with there only being a "line-height: 1.4em;" on the a.  No set height for the a.

ps. I know people will say FU IE6; no one develops for that anymore...but unfortunately my clients want it to work for that 10% of users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are experiencing the IE double padding bug. Try setting each submenu element to `display: inline-block`.

Comment: correct me if im wrong, but inline-block wont work in ie6 correct?

Comment: According to http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html it works in IE6 and 7 on elements that are `display: inline` by default. I think a list item is technically `display: list-item` (at least that's how it appears in Webkit) but maybe IE will treat that as `inline`.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html says this about "display: inline-block": "IE 6/7 accepts the value only on elements with a natural display: inline." So I don't think it will work when set directly on an <li>, because I think that has natural "display: list-item".
Edit: Jimmy Cuadra beat me by 4 seconds with a nice explanation using the same link I gave. +1 for his idea of trying it to see if IE7 is happy with display: inline-block on a <li>.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have IE7 to test, but have you tried to play with the padding and margin attributes of the li element?

I usually reset the styles of all element's padding margins spacings etc... to 0, and add some style rules that a need